# Converting simple Javascript to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onresize = fontResize;
    function fontResize() {
        document.body.style.fontSize = parseInt(document.documentElement.clientWidth/100) + 'px';
    }
</script>
```

Could someone have a crack at converting this to jQuery please, i have DIV's with class "features" and i need the P text to fill them when they are resized, so i need to font-size to grow/shrink along with the DIV. That make sense?

Thanks

Comment: When you encounter specific problems while writing your code, we will be happy to help you solve them. We will not, in most cases, write the code for you.

Comment: -2. What for? Some people vote down and don't explain. Highly unhelpful.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, perhaps i should have rephrased my question, i'm not too hot on Javascript so if someone could have explained it to me i could have a go at writing it.

Comment: The best way is to take a look at a good Javascript reference book or website to get an idea of the purpose of each function and keyword, then cross-reference with the [jQuery manual](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) to find an equivalent jQuery function or way of achieving the same result.

Comment: benhowdle89 rewrite it a bit and I'll be the first to '+1' you!

Comment: Ok, thank you, still think the onslaught of vote downs was a little hasty

Comment: @benhowdle89: The downvotes are not an attack on you. We use votes to indicate the usefulness of content on this site. If a question follows the [spirit of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and has the potential to help many people, it will be upvoted. If not, it will be downvoted. The ultimate goal is to produce a site with useful answers to practical, focused questions.

Comment: @benhowdle89 - your reputation implies you are more "hot" on javascript than you let on.

Comment: unfortunately, not too much on javascript, more jQuery :). But yes, i should know it better.

Comment: @benhowdle89: jQuery *is* JavaScript. A little off-topic, but why do you want to scale the font according to the size of the window? As a user that would really annoy me because I'd expect the font to stay the same so that I can see more of the page by making the window bigger...

Comment: @nnnnnn i'm very aware that jQuery is Javascript. Does not automatically mean i know Javascript just because i know jQuery. Also, i'm only scaling text inside some divs, not the entire body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
window.onresize = fontResize;
    function fontResize() {
    $('body').css('font-size',parseInt($('body').css('width'))/100) + 'px');

    }
```

Comment: Should use `$(window).resize`

Answer (score 3):

Here... jQuerified

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).bind('resize initialSize',function(){
        $('body').css('font-size', ($(window).width()/8) + 'px');
    }).trigger('initialSize');
});
```

Comment: @benhowdle89: Post an answer of the answer? I am wondering what would be the difference? :D

Comment: @Shef I noticed yours wasn't working so I fixed it my way, then you edited your way.

Answer (score 0):

This one takes in account the initial size

```
function fontResize(){
   $('body').css('font-size', ($(window).width()/8) + 'px');
}

fontResize();
$(window).resize( fontResize );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hpgfp/1

Comment: I made something similar in http://www.latin.fm for the sidebars gradient horizontal size

Comment: Why the redundancy of the `fontResize()`, where else will this function be used? Also, why not `$(window).resize(fontResize);`?

Comment: Also, why call the function `fontResize()`, when you could just trigger a `resize`?